# PHP Database Deployment git/capistrano

Tags: php, database, git, deployment, capistrano

I'm working for a company which is using PHP. There are different CMS Systems being used like Wordpress or Magento.
We are working with git having our own repository server and we have to deploy to different servers our different customers.

I've set up a deploymentscript using capistrano which works fine but the Database Synchronisation is quite tricky.

Imagine the live-database contains user data and I have to create some new features after the site already launched and there are loads of sql data within the database already. I personally work with a dummy database since I don't need any customer information.

How are you PHP geeks are deploying your databases? I don't want to change the contents but only migrate new or modified tables. I'm looking for a complete deployment solution for that. I'm also open for other options besides capistrano if needed. Especially with Magento I had serious problems to keep my database sync..

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You may be interested in the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589619/migrating-databases-using-phpmyadmins-tracking-mechanism/13693524#13693524

Comment: Sorry, I like your script for comparing databases but I'm pretty much looking for a migration solution which doesn't effect the data stored inside the database. Like 2 people working on a Typo3/Magento/WP/whatever project and using git to merge their versions. Tho they have to merge their databases as well through migrations. If the result has to be published the tables consisting live data shouldn't lose data but get updated. This isn't quite what your script does, tho I think it can be improved for accomplishing that goal.

Comment: My script doesn't affect any data at all and doesn't automatically make any changes, all it does is print out a list of differences between two MySQL databases. I'm not saying my script is the right tool for you however some of the other answers to that question have interesting solutions which I thought might interest you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recently I have discovered this project: http://dbv.vizuina.com/, but I don't have used it, otherwise Symfony has a similar feature called migrations and it works very well.

Comment: Sorry for the late response but this looks great and I'm going to try that. Thx