# update the structure modifications in exisiting database and tables

Tags: mysql, data-structures, sql-update

the problem that we face is:

we have 4 developpers who work together on creating a new programm. To stock their data they use Mysql database. each of them are working with their own database which have the same structure. the problem is when one developper finishes the table with introducing his modifications he exports it in sql file, so the other developper can import it in his database if he needs it. but when he tries to import the sql file file he got the error like this table already exists or this database already exists etc. is there any way to import only the modifications?

or the way to developpers to exchange their modifications in databases?

Comment: This thread may have some helpful information for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589619/migrating-databases-using-phpmyadmins-tracking-mechanism/13693524#13693524

Comment: What error messages are you getting exactly? The create table statements should be modified to check if the table already exists, for example: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [tablename]. Though honestly it seems like with that many developers you should have some kind of repository to store the files such as SVN or GIT.

Comment: they are using GIT to store their files, they export the sql files from their dqtq bqse to GIT and then from GIT they export files. in that step they face the problems, when they import sql file from GIT to their mysql database

Comment: if they will use CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST they can loose the data that they had before the import?

Comment: Maybe you should actually design your data model before implementing and refining it ? In normal cases a centralised database should work.